# How to color different parts of text drawn on a canvas in Android?

Tags: android, string, colors, android-canvas

I am trying to recreate the following animation:

[image: D3 liquid fill gauge]

The animation GIF can be accessed here: https://github.com/ugomeda/d3-liquid-fill-gauge

In this animation, as the waves rise and fall, the color of the text changes: the part of the text above the waves is colored dark blue and the part below the waves is colored light blue. Is there any way to implement this in Android?

I have implemented the rest of the animation exactly as shown in the image above:

[image: My implementation of liquid fill gauge]

Here's the code where I am drawing on canvas:

```
public void createShader(){

    mDefaultAngularFrequency = 2.0f * Math.PI / DEFAULT_WAVE_LENGTH_RATIO / getWidth();
    mDefaultAmplitude = (getHeight()) * DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE_RATIO;
    mDefaultWaterLevel = (getHeight())  * DEFAULT_WATER_LEVEL_RATIO;
    mDefaultWaveLength = getWidth();

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    final int endX = getWidth() + 1;
    final int endY = getHeight() + 1;

    float[] waveY = new float[endX];

    for (int beginX = 0; beginX < endX; beginX++) {
        double wx = beginX * mDefaultAngularFrequency;
        float beginY = (float) (mDefaultWaterLevel + mDefaultAmplitude * Math.sin(wx));
        canvas.drawLine(beginX, beginY, beginX, endY, mWavePaint);

        waveY[beginX] = beginY;
    }

    mWaveShader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    mWavePaint.setShader(mWaveShader);

}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Draw the outer circle
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, getWidth()/2 - 15, mCirclePaint);

    if (mWavePaint.getShader() == null) {
        createShader();
        mWavePaint.setShader(mWaveShader);
    }

    // scale shader according to mWaveLengthRatio and mAmplitudeRatio
    // this decides the size(mWaveLengthRatio for width, mAmplitudeRatio for height) of waves
    mShaderMatrix.setScale(mWaveLengthRatio / DEFAULT_WAVE_LENGTH_RATIO, mAmplitudeRatio / DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE_RATIO,
            0, mDefaultWaterLevel);
    // translate shader according to mWaveShiftRatio and mWaterLevelRatio
    // this decides the start position(mWaveShiftRatio for x, mWaterLevelRatio for y) of waves

    mShaderMatrix.postTranslate(mWaveShiftRatio * getWidth(),
            (DEFAULT_WATER_LEVEL_RATIO - mWaterLevelRatio) * getHeight());

    // assign matrix to invalidate the shader
    mWaveShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);

    //draw the inner circle
    float innerCircleRadius = getWidth()/2 - 30;
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2f, getHeight() / 2f, innerCircleRadius, mWavePaint);

    //draw the text inside the circles
    canvas.drawText(String.format("%.0f", mPercentageValue) + "%", getWidth() / 2 - 10,
            (getHeight() - mTextPaint.ascent()) / 2, mTextPaint);

}
```

And here's the code where I am animating the waves in the MainActivity:

```
ObjectAnimator waveShiftAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(l, "waveShiftRatio", 0f, 0.5f);
    waveShiftAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    waveShiftAnim.setDuration(mWaveAnimDuration);
    waveShiftAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animators.add(waveShiftAnim);
```

Comment: call `drawText` twice with differeent colors, the second one clipped by the wave

Comment: Thanks much, @pskink. Could tell me how I could go about doing the clipping?

Comment: or you can simply use two shaders with two different colors

Comment: @pskink, I tried PorterDuff, but it did not work out. However, your original idea of using drawText twice worked when I applied a different BitmapShader to the second drawText :) One more question: the color of the wave inside should be the same as the outer circle, but this is not the case. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: i have no idea what you are doing with `mCirclePaint`, in your code it is only used in `drawCircle` call. [here](http://pastebin.com/vW0caYV6) you can see how to draw it with two shaders (of course you can use a `android.graphics.ComposeShader` too if you want)

Comment: @pskink, I am initializing mCirclePaint and mWavePaint in the constructor like so, before using them for the drawCircle methods: mCirclePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mCirclePaint.setColor(0xff178BCA);
        mCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mCirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(10f);

        mWavePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mWavePaint.setColor(0xff178BCA); Both are set to the same color, yet the wave shows up as a lighter color. Could it be something to do with my use of BitmapShaders?

Comment: i dont see any difference here: http://pastebin.com/w1ZFGcVE

Comment: @pskink, ran your code. You're right, no difference in color with your code. But somehow mine still shows a color difference (see second image in the original question). Will try to figure it out. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: btw it can be done with one shader, see http://pastebin.com/8cG15A0L, after running click on the view to see it in action